# WSO2 inaccessible from internet

Tags: wso2

I'm running WSO 5 components cluster (KeyManager, Gateway, Publisher, Store, Traffic Manager),  each component has his own server and they are all exist in the same LAN.

Finally i got to a point where every component is running with no errors and i get this message below,

```
[2018-02-23 23:42:12,475]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server                                              
:  WSO2 API Manager-2.1.0
[2018-02-23 23:42:12,476]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 
Carbon started in 54 sec
[2018-02-23 23:42:12,720]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  
: https://172.31.25.234:9443/carbon/
[2018-02-23 23:42:12,720]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher 
DefaultContext : https://172.31.25.234:9443/publisher
[2018-02-23 23:42:12,720]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default 
Context : https://172.31.25.234:9443/store
```

wget -O- https://localhost:9443/publisher --no-check-certificate   - give me the page and i can see its running locally,  however , i cant reach the url from its external IP

Firewall disabled on CentOS. (firewall--cmd not exist)

I've tried also to use reverse proxy to my LAN publisher address:9443 but still no luck.

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: what's the ssl error?

Comment: @Bee  wget -O- https://localhost:9443/publisher --no-check-certificate
Works and will return the publisher page,  so i see its running locally but i cant access from outside of the LAN,  which settings can i check?   i tried messing with the hostname variables on carbon.xml

Comment: You are saying you can telnet to 9443 from outside but can't access the webapp?

Comment: @Bee i checked from outside with NMAP and the port 9443 is open on remote server   but i cant access the webapp

Comment: What do you see in browser when you access the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,  although there is no firewall not sure why publisher ui management was not accessible from internet through port 9443

Finally i changed the port to 8080  on repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml and it worked.